# Menu dropdown com v-if vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Como é possível adicionar um efeito `dropdown` a esse menu na vertical, de modo que ao colocar o mouse em cima ele abra a `ul` filha caso ela exista.

Pensei em fazer em fazer com `v-if` ao clicar na `li` pai, mas não sei como fazer isso sem instanciar um `object data` para cada seção... há uma alternativa mais adequada? segue o código.

```js
    new Vue({
     el : '#app',
      data : {
       modal : {
         estilos : {
           filhos : {
             padding : {
              metodo : 'outer'
              },
              margin : {
                metodo : 'outer'
              }
            }
          },
          containeres : {
           filhos : {
             div : {
               filhos : {
                 example : {
                   metodo : 'outer'
                  }
                }
              },
              header : {
               metodo : 'outer'
              }
            }    
          }
        }
      },
      methods : {
       teste (item) {
         if(this[item]) this[item]();
          else console.warn('metodo inexistente')
        },
        outer () {
         alert('outer');
        }
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <ul v-for="(item, key) in modal">
        <li>
          {{key}}
        </li>
        <ul  v-for="(item2, key2) in item.filhos">
           <li @click="teste(item2.metodo)">
             {{key2}}
           </li>
             <ul v-for="(item3, key3) in item2.filhos">
                 <li @click="teste(item3.metodo)">
                   {{key3}}
                 </li>
              </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Existe varias alternativas, alem de componentes já criados, você pode usar o evento de `mouseover` para fazer isso ao passar o mouse.

Comment: Qual o motivo de não usar um componente já existente?

Comment: Na verdade minha aplicação é muito específica, não consigo encontrar nada feito que atenta as exigências :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz da seguinte forma, cada item do menu terá um objeto `ativo`, que irá alternar entre o `mouseout` e o `mouseleave`...

```js
new Vue({
 el : '#app',
  data : {
   modal : {
      filhos: {
       estilos : {
          ativo: false,
          filhos : {
            padding : {
             ativo : false,
              metodo : 'outer'
            },
            margin : {
             ativo : false,
              metodo : 'outer'
            }
          }
        },
        containeres : {
          ativo : false,
          filhos : {
            div : {
             ativo : false,
              filhos : {
                example : {
                 ativo : false,
                  metodo : 'outer'
                }
              }
            },
            header : {
             ativo : false,
              metodo : 'outer'
            }
          }    
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods : {
   teste (item) {
     if(this[item])
      this[item]();
         else console.warn('metodo inexistente')
    },
    outer () {
     alert('outer');
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="(item, key) in modal.filhos" @mouseover="item.ativo = true" @mouseleave="item.ativo = false">
    <li>
      {{key}}
    </li>
    <ul @mouseover="item2.ativo = true" @mouseleave="item2.ativo = false" v-for="(item2, key2) in item.filhos" v-if="item.ativo === true">
       <li @click="teste(item2.metodo)">
         {{key2}}
        </li>
         <ul @mouseover="item3.ativo = true" @mouseleave="item3.ativo = false" v-for="(item3, key3) in item2.filhos" v-if="item2.ativo === true">
            <li @click="teste(item3.metodo)">
              {{key3}}
            </li>
          </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

O mais interessante é que com `v-if` a renderização soara melhor, pois esse menu irá conter milhares de itens, ou seja, somente ao passar o mouse em cima, o item será renderizado ao tirar ele será removido, descartando assim códigos desnecessários...